# Jolt transformation from list to list

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to convert a list to a list and filter out certain fields + flatten the structure in the list.

This is what I try to achieve:

```json
{
  "MatchedQuantity": 10,
  "matchCandidates": [
    {
      "sequence": 1,
      "duns": 402491757
    }
  ]
}
```

My input JSON looks like this:

```json
{
  "candidatesMatchedQuantity": 10,
  "matchDataCriteria": "Name and Address Lookup",
  "matchCandidates": [
    {
      "displaySequence": 1,
      "organization": {
        "duns": "402491757",
        "websiteAddress": [],
        "dunsControlStatus": {
          "operatingStatus": {
            "description": "Active",
            "dnbCode": 9074
          },
          "isMailUndeliverable": false
        },
        "primaryName": "Heineken N.V.",
        "tradeStyleNames": [],
        "telephone": [
          {
            "telephoneNumber": "0205239239",
            "isUnreachable": false
          }
        ],
        "primaryAddress": {
          "addressCountry": {
            "isoAlpha2Code": "NL",
            "name": "Netherlands"
          },
          "addressLocality": {
            "name": "Amsterdam"
          },
          "addressRegion": {},
          "postalCode": "1017 ZD",
          "postalCodeExtension": null,
          "streetAddress": {
            "line1": "Tweede Weteringplantsoen 21",
            "line2": null
          }
        },
        "mailingAddress": {
          "addressCountry": {
            "isoAlpha2Code": "NL",
            "name": "Netherlands"
          },
          "addressLocality": {
            "name": "AMSTERDAM"
          },
          "addressRegion": {},
          "postalCode": "1000AA",
          "postalCodeExtension": null,
          "streetAddress": {
            "line1": "PO BOX 28",
            "line2": null
          }
        },
        "registrationNumbers": [
          {
            "registrationNumber": "33011433",
            "typeDescription": "Trade Register Number",
            "typeDnBCode": 6256
          }
        ],
        "mostSeniorPrincipals": [
          {
            "fullName": "R G VAN DEN BRINK"
          }
        ],
        "isStandalone": false,
        "corporateLinkage": {
          "familytreeRolesPlayed": [
            {
              "description": "Parent/Headquarters",
              "dnbCode": 9141
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "nameMatchScore": 100
}
```

And the Jolt spec looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "candidatesMatchedQuantity": "MatchedQuantity",
      "matchCandidates": {
        "*": {
          "displaySequence": "matchCandidates[&1].sequence",
          "duns": "matchCandidates.organization.duns"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried quite some things but don't get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

You should go down the tree one level for `organization` while incrementing
the level of current identifiers `&2[&1]`(`matchCandidates[&1]`) to `&3[&2]` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "candidates*": "&(0,1)",
      "matchC*": {
        "*": {
          "displayS*": "&2[&1].s&(0,1)",
          "organization": {
            "duns": "&3[&2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```